# Ubuntu 14.04, Folder 'Places' pointing to extended partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, places

Before anything please excuse my wording if I refer to something in the wrong way (newbie).

I installed ubuntu 14.04 first and then alongside I installed Biolinux 8, when asked for the partition I gave ubuntu 14.04 the Principal one (1.9 Tb) and Biolinux the extended one (100 Gb). But now when I enter my computer the Folder points Places to the extended partition, so the Documents in ubuntu don't show up unless I go to the volume 1.9 Tb under Devices. I want the Document link under Places to point to the 1.9 Tb partition.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  1.2M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda4        95G   12G   79G  13% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G  140K   16G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1       2.8T  2.0T  788G  72% /media/sol/Seagate Expansion Drive
/dev/sda2       1.7T  650G  971G  41% /media/sol/8528e51a-b2df-4132-86e5-5054de0a575c
```

[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qXoc.png)

Comment: Please do not add SOLVED to the title. You answered your own question it show that the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The computer was booting from Biolinux 8 so I changed the boot order like so:

1. Boot machine, check for order of OS in menu (first line takes
   place 0, second line takes place 1, etc.)
2. Choose to boot in the default OS (in my case it was biolinux 8)
3. In terminal: gksu gedit /etc/default/grub (enter admin password)
   If you dont have gksu sudo apt-get install gksu
4. Change # of partition of desired OS in GRUB_DEFAULT=0 (e.g., GRUB_DEFAULT=2)
5. Save and close
6. In Terminal: sudo update-grub
7. Restart